# R code optimization with a data.frame

Tags: r, optimization, stack, raster

I have a Large SpatialPointDataFrame with 10570 elements, in which each row is a point with an associated date(some rows have the same date). This object has 4760 columns (it's the output of the extract() function between a RasterStack and the points) and each column corresponds to a date with an associated value (temperature).

Simplified example:

```
DATE2       BICHO   X2000.01.01   X2000.01.02   (...)   X2012.12.31
2009-04-08  Woody      20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
2009-04-09  Woody      20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
2009-04-10  Woody      20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
2004-11-30  Woody      20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
2004-12-01  Buzz       20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
2004-12-02  Buzz       20.7          19.2        ...         9.5
```

What I want to do is to create a new column (TP) in this data.frame, that contains the temperature for each corresponding date.

```
for(i in 11:4760){
  datas<-str_sub(colnames(pts@data[i]), start=2,end=11L)
  datas<-format(as.Date(datas, "%Y.%m.%d"),"%Y-%m-%d")
  for(j in seq_along(pts@data$TP)){
    print(c(i,j))   #just a print to see how fast is the code
    if(as.character(factor(pts$DATE2[j]))==datas){
      pts@data[j,]$TP<-pts@data[j,][i]
    }
  }
}
```

The code works but it's very slow, can anyone help me to optimize it?

Comment: There is a date in column 1 ["DATE2"] and there are dates in each column ["X2000.01.01"]. Which one do you mean with "corresponding date" ?

Comment: The corresponding date is DATE2. My objective is to find (in the columns) the value correspondent to the row date.

Comment: That's not clear.  Are you trying to match a column-named date with a date-value in the `DATE2` column? I'd also point out that, since your columns apparently are a sequence by day, you don't need to convert any of them.  Just take the column number and use some date/time function to add that value as "days" to your base date.

Comment: Yes, I want to match the DATE2 column with the value of the corresponding column-named date. But I don't understand how I would implement that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no date in the columns that matches the DATE2 dates, but I hope this works for you:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
df = data.table(df) 
dfm = data.table:::melt.data.table(df,
                               id.var = c("DATE2","BICHO"), 
                               variable.name = "date", 
                               value.name = "TP")
dfm[,date := gsub("X","",date)]
dfm[,date := ymd(date)]
dfm[,DATE2 := ymd(DATE2)]
dfm[DATE2 == date,]
```

Comment: Your code gives me a table with 4 colums: DATE2, BICHO, date and tp. date is a column filled with NAs and tp is a column filled with df values of TIME2,LAT2,LONG2,NAME_0 and NAME_1.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Did you install the lubridate and data.table libraries? It would be helpful if you would provide a data sample where there is a date - DATE2 match.